# Como trabajar con Transacction con EF Core 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

amigos tengo mi sistema en Windows Forms, con EF Core 6, Patron de Repositorio, Unidad de Trabajo y DevExpress, hasta aqui, todo bien, pero ahora que estoy entrando al desarrollo de tablas Cabecera, Detalle, quiero implementar Transacction. Ya agregue mi codigo y se los dejo, tengo una excepcion, el sistema la presenta, pero la transaccion no se deshace, pueden decirme que es lo malo en mi codigo, dejo imagen tambien de la Excepcion, pero siempre me graba el registro de la cabecera.

```
private void mpxSaveItem()
{
    // Cambiar el estado del Cursor al Iniciar el proceso principal
    System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor;
    // Declarar un Objeto 
    _operadorCorte = null;
    _operaporCorteDetalle = null;
    // Inicia el proceso de validacion y guardar registros
    try
    {
        // Inicia la sala de espera para guardar
        WaitFormHelper.ShowWaitForm(this);
        WaitFormHelper.SetWaitFormCaption(this, "Procesando las ListaDePrecios a Guardar");
        // LLamada al metodo guardar
        _operadorCorte = mpxCrearObjeto(_operadorCorte);
        //
        if (_operadorCorte != null)
        {
            using (var aoTransaction = _db.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    // Chequea que 
                    if (mmaster_grdvdeta.RowCount > 0)
                    {
                        ////SplashScreenManager.ShowWaitForm();
                        //// Grabar la Cabecera de la Lista de Precios
                        _operadorCorte = new OperaporCorte();
                        {
                            //_operadorCorte.IdListaPrecio = Convert.ToInt32(mseIdListaPrecio.EditValue);
                            _operadorCorte.IdCia = Convert.ToInt32(mseIdCia.EditValue);
                            _operadorCorte.Po = Convert.ToString(mtePO.EditValue);
                            _operadorCorte.TotalLineas = mmaster_grdvdeta.RowCount;
                            _operadorCorte.FchProceso = Convert.ToDateTime(mDEFchaProceso.EditValue);
                            _operadorCorte.QtyTotalCorte = Convert.ToInt32(mseTOTALPZAS.EditValue);
                            _operadorCorte.IdPeriodoNomina = this.mpxBuscarIdDelPeriodoDeNomina(_anNumeroDeEmpresa);
                            _operadorCorte.MesFiscal = Convert.ToDateTime(mDEFchaProceso.EditValue).Month;
                            _operadorCorte.AnioFiscal = Convert.ToDateTime(mDEFchaProceso.EditValue).Year;
                            _operadorCorte.IdEstado = Convert.ToInt32(mlueIdEstado.EditValue);
                            _operadorCorte.FchImpreso = DateTime.Now;
                            _operadorCorte.ValorTotalCorte = Convert.ToDecimal(mseTOTALVALOR.EditValue);
                            _operadorCorte.IdEmpleado = _annumeroDeEmpleado;
                        };
                        // Obtener los detalles del control XtraGrid.GridControl
                        _unidadTrabajo.opePorCorteCabe.Agregar(_operadorCorte);
                        //// Guardar por cada registro
                        _unidadTrabajo.mpxGuadar();
                        // Ordenar el GridData
                        mmaster_grdvdeta.BeginSort();
                        // Recorrer un grid
                        int Lineas = 0;
                        Lineas = mmaster_grdvdeta.RowCount;
                        int anRowCount = 0;
                        //
                        for (int i = 0; i < mmaster_grdvdeta.RowCount; i++)
                        {
                            anRowCount += 1;
                            _operaporCorteDetalle = new OperaporCorteDetalle();
                            //
                            _operaporCorteDetalle.IdCia = Convert.ToInt32(mmaster_grdvdeta.GetRowCellValue(i, "IdCia").ToString());
                            _operaporCorteDetalle.Idoperaxcorte = _operadorCorte.Idoperaxcorte;
                            _operaporCorteDetalle.IdOperacion = Convert.ToInt32(mmaster_grdvdeta.GetRowCellValue(i, "IdOperacion").ToString());
                            _operaporCorteDetalle.IdTipoProduc = Convert.ToInt32(mmaster_grdvdeta.GetRowCellValue(i, "IdTipoProduc").ToString());
                            _operaporCorteDetalle.CodigoBarra = Convert.ToString(mteCODIGOBARRA.EditValue);
                            _operaporCorteDetalle.FchDeCorte = Convert.ToDateTime(mDEFchaProceso.EditValue);
                            _operaporCorteDetalle.LetraIncentivo = "z";
                            _operaporCorteDetalle.Numbulto = Convert.ToString(mmaster_grdvdeta.GetRowCellValue(i, "Numbulto").ToString());
                            _operaporCorteDetalle.NumHoraExt = Convert.ToDecimal(mmaster_grdvdeta.GetRowCellValue(i, "ValorSamloc").ToString());
                            _operaporCorteDetalle.NumItem = anRowCount.ToString().PadLeft(3,'0');
                            _operaporCorteDetalle.NumLinea = anRowCount;
                            _operaporCorteDetalle.NumLote = Convert.ToInt32(mmaster_grdvdeta.GetRowCellValue(i, "NumLote").ToString());
                            _operaporCorteDetalle.QtyCorte = Convert.ToInt32(mmaster_grdvdeta.GetRowCellValue(i, "QtyCorte").ToString());
                            _operaporCorteDetalle.QtyOpera = Convert.ToInt32(mmaster_grdvdeta.GetRowCellValue(i, "QtyOpera").ToString());
                            _operaporCorteDetalle.TotalValorOperaFor = Convert.ToDecimal(mmaster_grdvdeta.GetRowCellValue(i, "TotalValorOperaFor"));
                            _operaporCorteDetalle.TotalValorOperaLoc = Convert.ToDecimal(mmaster_grdvdeta.GetRowCellValue(i, "TotalValorOperaLoc"));
                            _operaporCorteDetalle.TotalValorSamFor = Convert.ToDecimal(mmaster_grdvdeta.GetRowCellValue(i, "TotalValorSamFor").ToString());
                            _operaporCorteDetalle.TotalValorSamLoc = Convert.ToDecimal(mmaster_grdvdeta.GetRowCellValue(i, "TotalValorSamLoc").ToString());
                            _operaporCorteDetalle.ValorIncentivo = Convert.ToDecimal(mmaster_grdvdeta.GetRowCellValue(i, "ValorIncentivo").ToString());
                            _operaporCorteDetalle.ValorOperaFor = Convert.ToDecimal(mmaster_grdvdeta.GetRowCellValue(i, "ValorOperaFor").ToString());
                            _operaporCorteDetalle.ValorOperaLoc = Convert.ToDecimal(mmaster_grdvdeta.GetRowCellValue(i, "ValorOperaLoc").ToString());
                            _operaporCorteDetalle.ValorSamFor = Convert.ToDecimal(mmaster_grdvdeta.GetRowCellValue(i, "ValorSamFor").ToString());
                            _operaporCorteDetalle.ValorSamLoc = Convert.ToDecimal(mmaster_grdvdeta.GetRowCellValue(i, "ValorSamLoc").ToString());
                            //
                            _unidadTrabajo.opePorCorteDeta.Agregar(_operaporCorteDetalle);
                        }
                        //
                        //_unidadTrabajo.opePorCorteDeta.Agregar(_operaporCorteDetalle);
                        //// Guardar por cada registro
                        _unidadTrabajo.mpxGuadar();
                        //
                        aoTransaction.Commit();
                        aoTransaction.Dispose();
                        //
                        LogHelper.Info("Se Registro Correctamente el Movimiento de Corte Forma #:");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    aoTransaction.Rollback();
                    XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error - CRUD de ListaDePrecios.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    LogHelper.LogError("Error - En Lista de Precios", ex);
                }
            }
        }
        // Finaliza la sala de espera para guaardar
        WaitFormHelper.SetWaitFormCaption(this, "Sus datos se han guardado con éxito.");
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        WaitFormHelper.CloseWaitForm(this);
        XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error - CRUD Operación", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        LogHelper.LogError("Error - CRUD Ingreso Cortes", ex);
        //
    }
    finally
    {
        WaitFormHelper.CloseWaitForm(this);
        //Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        //
        mmaster_grdvdeta.EndSort();
        // Cambiar el estado
        this.mnAccFrm = ClsFxDatos.mexACCFRM.mvxLoad;
        //
        mpxViewEncabeTab(0);
        mpxObtenerTodos(_anNumeroDeEmpresa);
        /* Habilitar o Deshabilitar Controles de Edición */
        mpxEnabledCtls(mnAccFrm);
        //
        mpxClearView();
        //
        XtraMessageBox.Show("Se Guardo Correctamente el Registro", "Información Salvar - DXAProducSoft", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    // Restablecer el estado del Cursor por Defecto
    System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
}
```

Mi problema es que no se ejecuta o no se revierte el RollBack del Transacction, me pueden indicar que es lo malo que estoy haciendo por favor.

Saludos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]